# Объясните принцип работы программы

Tags: c

Программа удаляет подстроки S0 из строки S. Что делается после нахождения подстроки в строке?

```
char strrem(char *s, const char *s0)
{
char *temp;

   while(strstr(s, s0)){
      temp = strstr(s, s0);
      strcpy(temp, temp + strlen(s0));
   }    

   return *s;
}

int main(void)
{
   char s[100];
   char s0[100];
   gets(s);
   gets(s0);
   strrem(s, s0);

   printf("%s\n", s);

   system ("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите, что происходит:

#### 1. `char strrem(char *s, const char *s0)`

Мы передаем в функцию строку `char *s` и подстроку `const char *s0`, все вхождения которой в строку `s` будут удалены.

#### 2. `char *temp;`

Создаем указатель на `char`, который будет хранить адрес определенного символа из строки `s`.

#### 3. `while (strstr(s, s0))`

Функция [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) возвращает указатель на первое вхождение подстроки `s0` в строку `s`. Так что цикл означает следующее:

```
Пока(в строке s есть подстрока s0)
```

#### 4. `temp = strstr(s, s0);`

Здесь мы в указатель `temp` записываем адрес первого вхождения подстроки `s0` в строку `s`.

Пример:

```
Пусть:
    s = "Hello hello hello world hello."
    s0 = "el"

temp = strstr(s, s0);

Теперь:
    Hello hello hello world hello.
     ^
    temp указывает сюда.
```

#### 5. `strcpy(temp, temp + strlen(s0));`

Здесь мы как-бы перекрываем подстроку концом исходной строки:

```
temp
 ↓
Hello hello hello world hello.
   ↑ temp+strlen("el")

Теперь мы в место, на которое указывает temp, копируем все, что правее temp+strlen("el")
И получаем:

Hlo hello hello world hello.
```

И это продолжается пока в строке есть подстроки:

```
1. temp = strstr(s, s0);

    temp
     ↓
Hlo hello hello world hello. ⇒ Hlo hlo hello world hello.
       ↑ temp+strlen("el")

2. temp = strstr(s, s0);

        temp
         ↓
Hlo hlo hello world hello. ⇒ Hlo hlo hlo world hello.
           ↑ temp+strlen("el")

3. temp = strstr(s, s0);

                  temp
                   ↓
Hlo hlo hlo world hello. ⇒ Hlo hlo hlo world hlo.
                     ↑ temp+strlen("el")


В итоге получаем: Hlo hlo hlo world hlo.
```

P. S. *Как уже написал @AnT, код вызывает UB, так что стоит реализовать функцию немного по-другому.*

Answer (score 2):

Делается *неопределенное поведение*. Спецификация стандартной библиотеки не разрешает использовать функцию `strcpy` с перекрывающимися участками памяти. Данная программа в общем случае неработоспособна.